# AppLozic with IONIC APP

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, sdk, chat, applozic

When I use Applozic sdk in a blank ionic app everything works well and there is no problem. However, when I use it in an existing ionic app and when I want to chat with a connected user my app reloads/restarts. What could be the reason?

```
//Function to initialize chat plugin

$applozic.fn.applozic({
      userId: 'rabie_k', // Replace USER_ID with the user's unique identifier
      userName: 'rabie', // Replace DISPLAY_NAME with the user's name
      appId: 'my_application_key',  // Replace APPLICATION_KEY with the Application key received after Signup from https://www.applozic.com/signup.html
        ojq: $original,
        maxAttachmentSize: 25, //max attachment size in MB
        desktopNotification: true,
        locShare: false,
        googleApiKey: "AIzaSyDKfWHzu9X7Z2hByeW4RRFJrD9SizOzZt4",
        onInit: function() {  
                      $applozic.fn.applozic('loadTab', ''); 
                      //Todo: Register your push notification here. registerPushNotifications();
               }
   });
```